# Java DB Connectivity and virtuoso

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, linked-data, non-relational-database, openlink-virtuoso

During an IoT school project running for some time now I need to store json-ld data to openlink virtuoso triple store using only java and then be able to query them from a sparql endpoint of virtuoso. The data will be coming from sensors(not directly of course) through an mqtt broker. Up until the point that the data arrive to my java paho client and are parsed everything is ok.

But I don't know anything about jdbc and virtuoso is a bit difficult for me to handle(opposed to mongoDB for example which I find easy to work with). So as I started looking for java DB connectivity in general I came across Hibernate which is for relational data if I am not mistaken.

Is there any tool similar with Hibernate for java development but for non-relational data which I can use to connect my java application and virtuoso server for uploading json-ld data using rdf format?

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for tool recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Never used Virtuaoso before but this is the first google result: http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtJenaProvider

Comment: @MarkRotteveel thank you for pointing out my mistake. Should I edit the topic so it matches my question? (I have an account to stack for a while but never really used it before so I am not sure what should I do for the off-topic mistake)

Comment: @Phil thank you for your answer and for going into trouble googling for this! Yes I have seen the Jena provider and I believe that essentially it needs the virtuoso jdbc to work in parallel to perform changes to the database. But because some of the examples that virtuoso has in the documentation regarding java operations have depricated methods I am not sure how to proceed here.. This is why I started looking into jdbcs in general and found Hibernate. So my question relates to whether there is a similar framework that I can work with but for non-relational data(rdf triples specifically).

Comment: I'm not talking about the title, I mean that your question should not be asked on Stack Overflow (that is what off-topic means).